# I don't know why remove the html code in react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, next.js

Layout.js

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb" style={{margin: 0}}>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/movies">영화</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/showtimes">예매</a></li>
            <li class="ml-auto">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
        <script src="/static/js/sign_url.js"></script>
    );
  }
}
```

sign_url.js

```
if(getCookie("logged_in")=="true") {
  $(".breadcrumb > .ml-auto").html('<a href="/signout">signout</a>');
} else {
  $(".breadcrumb > .ml-auto").html('<div><a href="/signup">signup</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="/signin">signin</a></div>');
}
```

[image: video]

reload -> appear -> disappear

I don't know why remove the html code in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add componentDidMoun before rendering the component. Like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "/static/js/sign_url.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the decision about whether to display the *signup/signin* or *signout* links in the component like you normally would?:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const loggedIn = getCookie('logged_in') == 'true'
    return (
      <nav ...>
        <ol ...>
          ...
          <li className='ml-auto'>
            {loggedIn ? 
              <a href='/signout'>signout</a> : 
              <div>
                <a href='/signup'>signup</a>
                <a href='/signin'>signin</a>
              </div<
            }
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i can use the universal-cookie but did not working.

Comment: That's too bad because this would be a cleaner approach than injecting a `<script>`. Is there an error when trying to use `getCookie()` from the React component?

Comment: As far as i know getCookie() not supported command from react.

Comment: Where is this `getCookie()` defined?

Comment: @gureuso I just think if it works elsewhere, it should also work from a React component